# Re-formatting data frame in R

Tags: r

I have data frame like this:

```
df<-data.frame("ID"=c("1","2","3"),"A"=c("A01","A02","A03"),"B"=c("B01","B02","B03"),"C"=c("C01","C02","C03"))
```

I'm trying to get it in this format without headings but I couldn't:

```
1
A01,B01,CO1
2
A02,B02,C02
3
A03,B03,C03
```

This means that the for each ID I should have a new line with the values related to the ID ( a combined values of column 2:4) and they should be separated by a comma. I tried a kable package but I failed to do it can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll first create an artificial column `ABC` which has `A`, `B` and `C` pasted together with `,` as the delimiter. Then use `pivot_longer` to transform the structure to your desired output.

Just ignore `colnames(df2) <- NULL` if you would like to have column name in your output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(ABC = paste(c_across(A:C), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  select(ID, ABC) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = NULL) %>%
  as.data.frame()

colnames(df2) <- NULL
```

### Output

```
df2

1           1
2 A01,B01,C01
3           2
4 A02,B02,C02
5           3
6 A03,B03,C03
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df2 <- data.frame(chars=paste0(apply(df[, 2:3], 1, paste0, sep=",", collapse=""), df[, 4]))
df2
#         chars
# 1 A01,B01,C01
# 2 A02,B02,C02
# 3 A03,B03,C03
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the A01,B01,C01 to be in a new line , can you help me with this please?